# How to implement Laravel's jobs duplication management?

Tags: laravel, queue, jobs

I feel like this feature should be implemented by default.

Case is: I have multiple same jobs, with the same payload added to queue in term of application processing. Let's say `UpdateProfiletoElasticsearch` while different job is processing this update profile is stacked which laravel does not handle this by design - so job will be processed multiple times, which is unnecessary

Is there any laravel implementation or feature request due to this problem?

I'm going to implement job's checksum based on the payload to represent it's identity so that no duplicate will be added.

Please advise!

Comment: Why are there multiple instances of the same job?

Comment: Default implementation like `dispatch((new \App\Jobs\UpdateProfileESDirectory(\App\User::find(10)))->onQueue('testing'));` just stack them up in queue (I'm using DB, but I think that SQD will behave same). I do not manage and framework does not either by default.